# PySpark application submission is going on endless ACCEPTED STATE

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I was trying to submit a pyspark application using the command
`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster app.py`

And I am getting the **INFO Client: Application report for application_1663517069168_0003 (state: ACCEPTED) endlessly**

I have created an AWS EMR cluster with 1 master and 1 core node only and trying to submit application by connecting to the master node

````
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal/172.31.90.73:8032
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = memory-mb, units = Mi, type = COUNTABLE
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = vcores, units = , type = COUNTABLE
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (6144 MB per container)
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 2432 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
22/09/18 18:25:16 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
22/09/18 18:25:16 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
22/09/18 18:25:19 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-fb80e661-49d6-4738-8f29-351b4efdf337/__spark_libs__2372700901935780238.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1663517069168_0003/__spark_libs__2372700901935780238.zip
22/09/18 18:25:21 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/app.py -> hdfs://ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1663517069168_0003/app.py
22/09/18 18:25:21 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1663517069168_0003/pyspark.zip
22/09/18 18:25:21 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1663517069168_0003/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
22/09/18 18:25:21 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-fb80e661-49d6-4738-8f29-351b4efdf337/__spark_conf__1449366969974574614.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1663517069168_0003/__spark_conf__.zip
22/09/18 18:25:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
22/09/18 18:25:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
22/09/18 18:25:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/09/18 18:25:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/09/18 18:25:22 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/09/18 18:25:24 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1663517069168_0003 to ResourceManager
22/09/18 18:25:24 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1663517069168_0003
22/09/18 18:25:25 INFO Client: Application report for application_1663517069168_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/09/18 18:25:25 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: [Sun Sep 18 18:25:24 +0000 2022] Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Queue's AM resource limit exceeded.  Details : AM Partition = CORE; AM Resource Request = <memory:2432, max memory:6144, vCores:1, max vCores:4>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:3072, vCores:1>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:3072, vCores:1>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:2432, vCores:1>; 
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1663525524352
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-90-73.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1663517069168_0003/
     user: hadoop
22/09/18 18:25:26 INFO Client: Application report for application_1663517069168_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/09/18 18:25:27 INFO Client: Application report for application_1663517069168_0003 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/09/18 18:25:28 INFO Client: Application report .......```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pretty clear just by reading your log

> Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. **Queue's AM resource limit exceeded**.  Details : AM Partition = CORE; AM Resource Request = <memory:2432, max memory:6144, vCores:1, max vCores:4>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:3072, vCores:1>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:3072, vCores:1>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:2432, vCores:1>;

You're requesting more resources than your cluster has. You can change that by giving more cores to your EMR cluster

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same application by adding another node and it worked!